# In Angular multiple http requests fire when I redirect from one component to another component (in increasing order), do we have any solution for it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-material

In my project there is one API which is called on init method when component is called as follows:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCurrentUserpost();
}
```

and the function looks like this

```
getCurrentUserpost(){
    this.friend.getAllFriendsPost(this.friendsId).subscribe(res => {
        this.allPosts = res;
    });
}
```

and the service API function looks like the following

```
getAllFriendsPost(ids:any){
    return this.http.post(this.BaseUrl+'/allfriendspost',ids);
}
```

When I navigate between component using routeLink then every time when I visit component where I have added this API, it will call the API multiple times at the same time with increasing order.

See the network tap where you can see multiple API calls are done

[image]

Can anyone advise me how to I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a memory leak. You need to unsubscribe from the observable.

One of multiple possibilities would be to use `take(1)` rxjs-operator.

```
getCurrentUserpost(){
this.friend.getAllFriendsPost(this.friendsId).pipe(
  take(1),
).subscribe(res => {
          this.allPosts = res;
        });
}
```

---

Just to mention some other possibilities:

- async pipe
- takeUntil operator (or other take*) operators
- Subscription.unsubscribe